# Php: If input value is x, y, or z do stuff

Tags: php

In a html page I have this input:

```
<input type="text" name="my_input" id="my_input">
```

Using PHP, if the user enters in the input the words "sun", "moon", "stars", I want the script to do stuff.

Something like this, just don't know how to write it correctly:

```
if (my_input.value == "sun,moon,stars") {
do stuff
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use the `in_array()` function in your `if` statement.

Comment: Can you plase provide the full code please? Pretty good with javascript but complete php beginner here...

Comment: Lucky guy that someone already did your homework ;-)

Comment: Your question is tagged `php` but you example looks like javascript, which do you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use php's **[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)**:

```
if(preg_match("/^(sun|moon|stars)$/i", $_POST['my_input']) === 1) {
    // success
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [**`in_array()`**](https://www.php.net/in_array)

```
if( in_array($_POST['my_input'], array("sun", "moon", "stars")) ) {
   //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways you can achieve this. Some better than others, personally I prefer `in_array`

in_array

```
if (in_array($value, array("sun", "moon", "stars"))) {
    // Do something
}
```

If statement

```
if ($value == "sun" || $value == "moon" || $value == "stars") {
    // Do something
}
```

Switch

```
switch ($value) {
    case "sun":
    case "moon":
    case "stars":
        // Do something
    break;
}
```

Note there are more ways you can achieve this. The above are just a few.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy
You can get the value of text fields by post method:

```
<input type="text" name="my_input" id="my_input">

if ($_POST['my_input'] == "sun" || $_POST['my_input'] == "moon" || $_POST['my_input'] == "stars" ) {
do stuff
}
```

Or you can use in_array function.

Comment: That's not as elegant as the `in_array()` solution.

Comment: Also, equality test operator is `==`, not `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is tagged with php, your example code looks like javascript, so here is a javascript solution:

```
<input type="text" name="my_input" id="my_input" onblur="doStuff(this.value);">
<script>
function doStuff(val){

    if(["sun", "moon", "stars"].indexOf(val)!= -1){
       alert("found");
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. It looks like javascript because it's the only programming language I know... Just did not know how to write it in php.. :)